# Android Hal is not registered at runtime in Android R(11)

Tags: android, c++, hal, android-native-library

I added my hal interface in manifest.xml, vendor_compatibilityMatrix.xml, and also in device.mk.
And also I have created hal.rc file as well for my hal.
but at boot time i am getting below error....

03-07 09:53:19.541 242 242 I hwservicemanager: Since vendor.OEM.frameworks.input.inputdeviceI@1.0::IinputServer/default is not registered, trying to start it as a lazy HAL.

so, could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong or i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Change "IinputServer" HAL Name to "IInputServer". As coding guidelines in Hal Interface name should be start with I followed by Capital letter.

https://source.android.google.cn/devices/architecture/hidl/code-style

Comment: Please make the link clickable

Comment: Here is the clickable Link(http://source.android.google.cn/devices/architecture/hidl/code-style)

Comment: I fixed it for you this time